# ¿Como programar una aplicación de Windows Forms con el aspecto de Windows 10?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms, formularios, windows10

Soy novato en C# y .NET y estoy empezando a desarrollar aplicaciones en Windows Forms, pero me ha aparecido la siguiente duda: ¿que hay que hacer o que hay que descargar o como programar para poder hacer Windows Forms con los menús y botones y ventanas etc con el aspecto de Windwos 10? Es decir, así con los colores y el aspecto que tiene.

Estoy utilizando el Visual Studio programando aplicaciones con C# y no encuentra ninguna propiedad ni nada que me indique como poner este aspecto. Supongo que será instalando algún framework pero no se ni como se llama ni como se instala (si es un ejecutable normal) ni nada.

Saludos.

Comment: Tienes dos opciones básicamente. Por un lado, usar WPF con alguna librería que te de esa apariencia ([MahApps Metro](https://mahapps.com/) o programar tu aplicación usando [Windows Universal](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/uwp/get-started/universal-application-platform-guide). Es posible que exista alguna librería para windows forms, pero yo no te lo recomendaría.

Comment: Perfecto, le echaré un vistazo. He visto que a la solucion en Visual Studio se le puede instalar el Metro Framework y tiene ese aspecto. Es "bueno" ese framework?

Comment: Ese no es franework, son componentes que tienen el aspecto de aplicaciones UWP. El problema es que tendrás que usar solo esos componentes, si usas otros que no sean los que vienen incluídos ahí, se verá rara tu aplicación.

Comment: Windows forms para Windows 10 no es lo más recomendable. Es mejor usar framework más modernos como WPF o UWP.

Comment: @Xam eso depende del proyecto, Winforms funciona perfectamente en windows 10, y si solo quieres algo sencillo, o no te preocupa mucho que la interfaz de usuario sea algo sencilla, usar Winforms es bastante válido.

Answer (score 4):

Si quieres hacerlo en `winform` podrias usar componente que den el aspecto, como podria ser

[MetroFramework](https://thielj.github.io/MetroFramework/)

esta claro que estaras limitado al diseño que esta libreria defina, si necesita algun componente que esta por fuera de este no tendras un diseño que aplicar, pero hay tambien de terceros como ser Telerik, DevExpress, etc, pero estos ya serian suit con licencia

Lo que si recomendaria es que si vas a programar para Win10 ya no uses `winform` sino que veas de saltar a la proxima generacion de aplicacion desktop con un desarrollo `Universal Windows Platform (UWP)`

[Introducción al diseño de aplicaciones para UWP](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/uwp/design/basics/design-and-ui-intro)

como veras estaras utilizando `xaml` con lo que podras aplicar los diseños definidos por el `Fluent Design`